# Find parameter values that satsify logical formula in Prolog

Tags: prolog, logical-operators

I have a fact base of a single logical formula, e.g.

```
check(A,B) :- A,B.
```

I can query `check(true,true).` or `check(true,false).` and the compiler will give correct results. But I would like to also make queries where some parameters are variables, to obtain all values of those variables that make the query true. E.g., I'd like to query `check(X,Y).` and obtain `X=true, Y=true.`, or `check(X,true)` and obtain `X=true`. However, I can't get it to work even for this trivial case, nor find the solution anywhere. All queries with variables return `Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`.

I've also tried `findall(X,check(true,X),Solution).` and various variants using `bagof` or `setof`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
check_both(X, Y) :-
    check_single(X),
    check_single(Y).

check_single(true) :- !.
check_single(X) :- call(X).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- check_both(X, Y).
X = Y, Y = true.

?- X=1, check_both(X=1, Y).
X = 1,
Y = true.

?- X=1, check_both(X=2, Y).
false.

?- X=1, check_both(true, X=1).
X = 1.

?- X=1, check_both(true, X=2).
false.

?- member(X, [a, b]), check_both(X=Y, true).
X = Y, Y = a ;
X = Y, Y = b.
```

Comment: I've tried taking out parts to see if it would break the solution, and it seems like replacing the last two lines with `check_single(true).` preserves the intended effect, so all that was required was to replace `X` with a trivial predicate that is true iff `X` is true. (But why?)

Comment: The `check_single(true)` line works as intended, when the first argument is uninstantiated *or* true. This is Prolog *unification* - part of what makes Prolog so special/powerful.